# Sort Ruby array using the Post objects it contains

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, arrays, sorting, mongoid

I have a Ruby array which contains Post objects (a Mongoid model) with a `created_at` method returning a `Time` object. What I want is to sort that array using that method (which is present on every element on the array). I tried `@posts.sort_by {|post| post.created_at}` but that didn't work. How could I achieve this? Thanks!

### EDIT: Example of the array:

`[#<Post _id: 4ffd5184e47512e60b000003, _type: nil, created_at: 2012-07-11 10:12:20 UTC, title: "TestSecond", description: "TestSecond", slug: "assa", user_id: 4ffc4fd8e47512aa14000003>, #<Post _id: 4ffd518ee47512e60b000004, _type: nil, created_at: 2012-07-11 10:12:30 UTC, title: "TestFirst", description: "TestFirst", slug: "assadd", user_id: 4ffc4fd8e47512aa14000003>]`.

## EDIT #2: I'm getting that @posts arra with:

```
@posts = Array.new

@user.following.each do |user|
   user.posts.each do |p|
    @posts << p
   end
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure why you have an array here. Normally, with Mongoid querying, you should have a `Mongoid::Criteria` instance, which you can `desc(:created_by)` or `asc(:created_by)` on, in order to sort.

Still, can't think of any reason `sort_by` doesn't work for properly for you, works great on my app (just tried at console).

**UPD:**

```
@user.following.each do |user|
   user.posts.each do |p|
    @posts << p
   end
end
```

Well, to still have a mongoid collection there, something like this might be done:

```
@posts = @user.following.map(&:posts).inject { |posts, post| posts.concat post }
```

Now, you can `@posts.desc(:created_at)`.

**UPD2:**

Also, for purpose of having a cleaner code, you could define a `posts_from_following` on `User`:

```
class User
  def posts_from_following
    following.map(&:posts).inject { |posts, post| posts.concat post }
  end
end
```

and then, just do

```
@posts = @user.posts_from_following.desc(:created_at)
```

in your controller.

Comment: I'm not doing a query for it, I'm using embedded documents. Post is embedded in User with `has_many``

Comment: Well, collection returned by `user.posts` is sortable via `desc`/`asc`, too.

Comment: I tried it on actual code, and on console, but posts don't get sorted :( this is the relevant part on the console: http://d.pr/n/5mew

Comment: Oops, a typo, should have been `@posts.desc(:created_at)`, not `@posts.desc(:created_by)`. Could you please try with `:created_at`?

Comment: Also, see my proposed, more idiomatic variant in UPD2.

Answer (score 0):

```
@posts.sort_by &:created_at

@posts.sort {|a, b| a.created_at <=> b.created_at }
```